# Como converter de List<> para IList<> usando o Automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd, automapper

Preciso converter com o automapper uma List para IList sabendo que ambas estão em classes diferentes e uma delas possui construtor. Isso é possível?
Estou usando o Automapper 6.2.2.

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Nome { get; set; }   
}

public class MinhasPessoas
{
    public List<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RegisterNewPessoas
{
    public IList<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }

    RegisterNewPessoas(IList<Pessoa> pessoas)
    {
        Pessoas = pessoas;
    }
}
```

Mapeamento:

```
CreateMap<MinhasPessoas, RegisterNewPessoa>()
    .ConstructUsing(ps => new RegisterNewPessoa(//Converter as listas aqui));
```

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa fazer conversão nenhuma. `List<>` implementa `IList<>`, então qualquer instância de `List<>` pode ser atribuída a uma variável `IList<>`.

Nem sei se é necessário usar o método `ConstructUsing` nesse caso. Se for, é só fazer a atribuição.

```
ConstructUsing(ps => new RegisterNewPessoa { Pessoas = ps.Pessoas }
```

[Veja um exemplo funcional no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YibYeU)